# Error installing realpath on Mac running High Sierra

Tags: macports, macos-high-sierra, realpath

Trying to install on High Sierra:

```
$ sudo /opt/local/bin/port install realpath
---> Fetching archive for realpath
---> Attempting to fetch realpath-1.0.1_1.darwin_17.x86_64.tbz2 from https://packages.macports.org/realpath
---> Attempting to fetch realpath-1.0.1_1.darwin_17.x86_64.tbz2.rmd160 from https://packages.macports.org/realpath
---> Installing realpath @1.0.1_1
---> Activating realpath @1.0.1_1
---> Cleaning realpath
---> Scanning binaries for linking errors
---> No broken files found.
---> Found 10 broken ports, determining rebuild order
You can always run 'port rev-upgrade' again to fix errors.
The following ports will be rebuilt:
blosc @1.5.2
llvm-3.4 @3.4.2
cctools @862+llvm34
db48 @4.8.30
py27-numexpr @2.4
gettext @0.19.4
pcre @8.36
swig @3.0.5
hdf5 @1.8.14+cxx
zmq @3.2.5
Continue? [Y/n]: y
---> Fetching archive for lz4
---> Attempting to fetch lz4-1.9.3_1.darwin_17.x86_64.tbz2 from https://packages.macports.org/lz4
---> Attempting to fetch lz4-1.9.3_1.darwin_17.x86_64.tbz2.rmd160 from https://packages.macports.org/lz4
---> Installing lz4 @1.9.3_1
---> Activating lz4 @1.9.3_1
---> Cleaning lz4
---> Fetching archive for zlib
---> Attempting to fetch zlib-1.2.11_0.darwin_17.x86_64.tbz2 from https://packages.macports.org/zlib
---> Attempting to fetch zlib-1.2.11_0.darwin_17.x86_64.tbz2.rmd160 from https://packages.macports.org/zlib
---> Installing zlib @1.2.11_0
---> Cleaning zlib
---> Deactivating zlib @1.2.8_0
---> Cleaning zlib
---> Activating zlib @1.2.11_0
---> Cleaning zlib
---> Fetching archive for libiconv
---> Attempting to fetch libiconv-1.16_1.darwin_17.x86_64.tbz2 from https://packages.macports.org/libiconv
---> Attempting to fetch libiconv-1.16_1.darwin_17.x86_64.tbz2.rmd160 from https://packages.macports.org/libiconv
---> Installing libiconv @1.16_1
---> Cleaning libiconv
---> Deactivating libiconv @1.14_0
---> Cleaning libiconv
---> Activating libiconv @1.16_1
---> Cleaning libiconv
---> Fetching archive for ncurses
---> Attempting to fetch ncurses-6.2_1.darwin_17.x86_64.tbz2 from https://packages.macports.org/ncurses
---> Attempting to fetch ncurses-6.2_1.darwin_17.x86_64.tbz2.rmd160 from https://packages.macports.org/ncurses
---> Installing ncurses @6.2_1
---> Cleaning ncurses
---> Deactivating ncurses @5.9_2
---> Cleaning ncurses
---> Activating ncurses @6.2_1
---> Cleaning ncurses
---> Computing dependencies for gettext
---> Fetching archive for gettext
---> Attempting to fetch gettext-0.19.8.1_2.darwin_17.x86_64.tbz2 from https://packages.macports.org/gettext
---> Attempting to fetch gettext-0.19.8.1_2.darwin_17.x86_64.tbz2.rmd160 from https://packages.macports.org/gettext
---> Installing gettext @0.19.8.1_2
---> Cleaning gettext
---> Computing dependencies for gettext
---> Deactivating gettext @0.19.4_0
---> Cleaning gettext
---> Activating gettext @0.19.8.1_2
---> Cleaning gettext
---> Computing dependencies for xz
---> Fetching archive for xz
---> Attempting to fetch xz-5.2.5_0.darwin_17.x86_64.tbz2 from https://packages.macports.org/xz
---> Attempting to fetch xz-5.2.5_0.darwin_17.x86_64.tbz2.rmd160 from https://packages.macports.org/xz
---> Installing xz @5.2.5_0
---> Cleaning xz
---> Computing dependencies for xz
---> Deactivating xz @5.2.1_0
---> Cleaning xz
---> Activating xz @5.2.5_0
---> Cleaning xz
---> Computing dependencies for zstd
---> Fetching archive for zstd
---> Attempting to fetch zstd-1.5.0_0.darwin_17.x86_64.tbz2 from https://packages.macports.org/zstd
---> Attempting to fetch zstd-1.5.0_0.darwin_17.x86_64.tbz2.rmd160 from https://packages.macports.org/zstd
---> Installing zstd @1.5.0_0
---> Activating zstd @1.5.0_0
---> Cleaning zstd
---> Fetching archive for lzo2
---> Attempting to fetch lzo2-2.10_0.darwin_17.x86_64.tbz2 from https://packages.macports.org/lzo2
---> Attempting to fetch lzo2-2.10_0.darwin_17.x86_64.tbz2.rmd160 from https://packages.macports.org/lzo2
---> Installing lzo2 @2.10_0
---> Cleaning lzo2
---> Deactivating lzo2 @2.08_0
---> Cleaning lzo2
---> Activating lzo2 @2.10_0
---> Cleaning lzo2
---> Computing dependencies for snappy
---> Fetching archive for snappy
---> Attempting to fetch snappy-1.1.9_2.darwin_17.x86_64.tbz2 from https://packages.macports.org/snappy
---> Attempting to fetch snappy-1.1.9_2.darwin_17.x86_64.tbz2.rmd160 from https://packages.macports.org/snappy
---> Installing snappy @1.1.9_2
---> Activating snappy @1.1.9_2
---> Cleaning snappy
---> Computing dependencies for blosc
---> Fetching archive for blosc
---> Attempting to fetch blosc-1.21.0_0.darwin_17.x86_64.tbz2 from https://packages.macports.org/blosc
---> Attempting to fetch blosc-1.21.0_0.darwin_17.x86_64.tbz2.rmd160 from https://packages.macports.org/blosc
---> Installing blosc @1.21.0_0
---> Cleaning blosc
---> Computing dependencies for blosc
---> Deactivating blosc @1.5.2_0
---> Cleaning blosc
---> Activating blosc @1.21.0_0
---> Cleaning blosc
---> Fetching archive for libffi
---> Attempting to fetch libffi-3.3_1.darwin_17.x86_64.tbz2 from https://packages.macports.org/libffi
---> Attempting to fetch libffi-3.3_1.darwin_17.x86_64.tbz2.rmd160 from https://packages.macports.org/libffi
---> Installing libffi @3.3_1
---> Cleaning libffi
---> Deactivating libffi @3.2.1_0
---> Cleaning libffi
---> Activating libffi @3.3_1
---> Cleaning libffi
---> Fetching archive for db48
---> Attempting to fetch db48-4.8.30_4.darwin_17.x86_64.tbz2 from https://packages.macports.org/db48
---> Attempting to fetch db48-4.8.30_4.darwin_17.x86_64.tbz2.rmd160 from https://packages.macports.org/db48
---> Unable to uninstall db48 @4.8.30_4, the following ports depend on it:
---> python27 @2.7.9_0
Warning: Uninstall forced. Proceeding despite dependencies.
---> Deactivating db48 @4.8.30_4
---> Cleaning db48
---> Uninstalling db48 @4.8.30_4
---> Cleaning db48
---> Installing db48 @4.8.30_4
---> Activating db48 @4.8.30_4
---> Cleaning db48
---> Computing dependencies for readline
---> Fetching archive for readline
---> Attempting to fetch readline-8.1.000_0.darwin_17.x86_64.tbz2 from https://packages.macports.org/readline
---> Attempting to fetch readline-8.1.000_0.darwin_17.x86_64.tbz2.rmd160 from https://packages.macports.org/readline
---> Installing readline @8.1.000_0
---> Activating readline @8.1.000_0
---> Cleaning readline
---> Computing dependencies for gdbm
---> Fetching archive for gdbm
---> Attempting to fetch gdbm-1.19_0.darwin_17.x86_64.tbz2 from https://packages.macports.org/gdbm
---> Attempting to fetch gdbm-1.19_0.darwin_17.x86_64.tbz2.rmd160 from https://packages.macports.org/gdbm
---> Installing gdbm @1.19_0
---> Cleaning gdbm
---> Computing dependencies for gdbm
---> Deactivating gdbm @1.11_1
---> Cleaning gdbm
---> Activating gdbm @1.19_0
---> Cleaning gdbm
---> Computing dependencies for perl5.28
---> Fetching archive for perl5.28
---> Attempting to fetch perl5.28-5.28.3_2.darwin_17.x86_64.tbz2 from https://packages.macports.org/perl5.28
---> Attempting to fetch perl5.28-5.28.3_2.darwin_17.x86_64.tbz2.rmd160 from https://packages.macports.org/perl5.28
---> Installing perl5.28 @5.28.3_2
---> Activating perl5.28 @5.28.3_2
---> Cleaning perl5.28
---> Computing dependencies for perl5
---> Fetching archive for perl5
---> Attempting to fetch perl5-5.28.3_0+perl5_28.darwin_17.noarch.tbz2 from https://packages.macports.org/perl5
---> Attempting to fetch perl5-5.28.3_0+perl5_28.darwin_17.noarch.tbz2.rmd160 from https://packages.macports.org/perl5
---> Installing perl5 @5.28.3_0+perl5_28
---> Cleaning perl5
---> Computing dependencies for perl5
---> Deactivating perl5 @5.12.4_0+perl5_16
---> Cleaning perl5
---> Activating perl5 @5.28.3_0+perl5_28
---> Cleaning perl5
---> Fetching archive for llvm_select
---> Attempting to fetch llvm_select-2_0.darwin_17.noarch.tbz2 from https://packages.macports.org/llvm_select
---> Attempting to fetch llvm_select-2_0.darwin_17.noarch.tbz2.rmd160 from https://packages.macports.org/llvm_select
---> Installing llvm_select @2_0
---> Cleaning llvm_select
---> Deactivating llvm_select @1.0_0
---> Cleaning llvm_select
---> Activating llvm_select @2_0
---> Cleaning llvm_select
---> Computing dependencies for llvm-3.4
---> Fetching archive for llvm-3.4
---> Attempting to fetch llvm-3.4-3.4.2_14.darwin_17.x86_64.tbz2 from https://packages.macports.org/llvm-3.4
---> Attempting to fetch llvm-3.4-3.4.2_14.darwin_17.x86_64.tbz2.rmd160 from https://packages.macports.org/llvm-3.4
---> Installing llvm-3.4 @3.4.2_14
---> Cleaning llvm-3.4
---> Computing dependencies for llvm-3.4
---> Deactivating llvm-3.4 @3.4.2_6
---> Cleaning llvm-3.4
---> Activating llvm-3.4 @3.4.2_14
---> Cleaning llvm-3.4
---> Computing dependencies for libedit
---> Fetching archive for libedit
---> Attempting to fetch libedit-20210216-3.1_0.darwin_17.x86_64.tbz2 from https://packages.macports.org/libedit
---> Attempting to fetch libedit-20210216-3.1_0.darwin_17.x86_64.tbz2.rmd160 from https://packages.macports.org/libedit
---> Installing libedit 20210216-3.1_0
---> Cleaning libedit
---> Computing dependencies for libedit
---> Deactivating libedit 20140620-3.1_0
---> Cleaning libedit
---> Activating libedit 20210216-3.1_0
---> Cleaning libedit
---> Fetching archive for bzip2
---> Attempting to fetch bzip2-1.0.8_0.darwin_17.x86_64.tbz2 from https://packages.macports.org/bzip2
---> Attempting to fetch bzip2-1.0.8_0.darwin_17.x86_64.tbz2.rmd160 from https://packages.macports.org/bzip2
---> Installing bzip2 @1.0.8_0
---> Cleaning bzip2
---> Deactivating bzip2 @1.0.6_0
---> Cleaning bzip2
---> Activating bzip2 @1.0.8_0
---> Cleaning bzip2
---> Computing dependencies for openssl
---> Fetching archive for openssl
---> Attempting to fetch openssl-1.1.1k_0.darwin_17.x86_64.tbz2 from https://packages.macports.org/openssl
---> Attempting to fetch openssl-1.1.1k_0.darwin_17.x86_64.tbz2.rmd160 from https://packages.macports.org/openssl
---> Installing openssl @1.1.1k_0
---> Cleaning openssl
---> Computing dependencies for openssl
---> Deactivating openssl @1.0.2_0
---> Cleaning openssl
---> Activating openssl @1.1.1k_0
---> Cleaning openssl
---> Fetching archive for icu
---> Attempting to fetch icu-67.1_4.darwin_17.x86_64.tbz2 from https://packages.macports.org/icu
---> Attempting to fetch icu-67.1_4.darwin_17.x86_64.tbz2.rmd160 from https://packages.macports.org/icu
---> Installing icu @67.1_4
---> Activating icu @67.1_4
---> Cleaning icu
---> Computing dependencies for libxml2
---> Fetching archive for libxml2
---> Attempting to fetch libxml2-2.9.12_1.darwin_17.x86_64.tbz2 from https://packages.macports.org/libxml2
---> Attempting to fetch libxml2-2.9.12_1.darwin_17.x86_64.tbz2.rmd160 from https://packages.macports.org/libxml2
---> Installing libxml2 @2.9.12_1
---> Cleaning libxml2
---> Computing dependencies for libxml2
---> Deactivating libxml2 @2.9.2_2
---> Cleaning libxml2
---> Activating libxml2 @2.9.12_1
---> Cleaning libxml2
---> Computing dependencies for xar
---> Fetching archive for xar
---> Attempting to fetch xar-1.8.0.452_0.darwin_17.x86_64.tbz2 from https://packages.macports.org/xar
---> Attempting to fetch xar-1.8.0.452_0.darwin_17.x86_64.tbz2.rmd160 from https://packages.macports.org/xar
---> Installing xar @1.8.0.452_0
---> Activating xar @1.8.0.452_0
---> Cleaning xar
---> Fetching archive for libcxx
---> Attempting to fetch libcxx-5.0.1_4.darwin_17.noarch.tbz2 from https://packages.macports.org/libcxx
---> Attempting to fetch libcxx-5.0.1_4.darwin_17.noarch.tbz2.rmd160 from https://packages.macports.org/libcxx
---> Installing libcxx @5.0.1_4
---> Activating libcxx @5.0.1_4
---> Cleaning libcxx
---> Computing dependencies for llvm-10
---> Fetching archive for llvm-10
---> Attempting to fetch llvm-10-10.0.1_1.darwin_17.x86_64.tbz2 from https://packages.macports.org/llvm-10
---> Attempting to fetch llvm-10-10.0.1_1.darwin_17.x86_64.tbz2.rmd160 from https://packages.macports.org/llvm-10
---> Installing llvm-10 @10.0.1_1
---> Activating llvm-10 @10.0.1_1
---> Cleaning llvm-10
---> Computing dependencies for cctools
---> Fetching archive for cctools
---> Attempting to fetch cctools-949.0.1_1+llvm10.darwin_17.x86_64.tbz2 from https://packages.macports.org/cctools
---> Attempting to fetch cctools-949.0.1_1+llvm10.darwin_17.x86_64.tbz2.rmd160 from https://packages.macports.org/cctools
---> Installing cctools @949.0.1_1+llvm10
---> Cleaning cctools
---> Computing dependencies for cctools
---> Deactivating cctools @862_1+llvm34
---> Cleaning cctools
---> Activating cctools @949.0.1_1+llvm10
---> Cleaning cctools
Error: rev-upgrade failed: invalid command name "::registry::entry4"
Error: Follow https://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets if you believe there is a bug.
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get realpath by running:

```
brew install coreutils
```

Comment: It is recommended to only have one package manager installed at a time.  Having both MacPorts and Homebrew can lead to problems that are basically unreproducible.

Answer (score 0):

What is the output from 'sudo /opt/local/bin/port diagnose'?  And is there some reason that you haven't got '/opt/local/bin' in your PATH?

Comment: `Error: process_cmd failed: can't read "msg": no such variable`

Comment: That would indicate that your MacPorts installation is severely damaged.  Should you wish to continue with MacPorts, you could most likely fix the problem by reinstalling MacPorts from the appropriate dmg.